# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.<init>(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)V

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I am getting `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.<init>(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)V` with spring-cloud-dependencies version Camden SR5.
 Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue as reported here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/issues/70

and currently, the workaround (suggested from the above) is:

> You have two options here: either to upgrade the version of Spring Integration Kafka to 2.1.0 and bring it inline with the rest of the Spring Boot dependency set, or downgrading the Spring Kafka version as you did. Using Dalston would bring a consistent dependency set.